# Check if array exist by two keys with PHP

Tags: php

I'd like to check if array exist by two keys: id and type

This code just check by id:

```
 if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
   $type = $_POST['type'];
 } 
 else {
   $type = '';
 }

 if (array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity'] += $quantity;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $line;
  }
```

I have tried with this code but it doesn't work:

```
 if (array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['cart']) && array_key_exists($type, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity'] += $quantity;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $line;
    }
```

**$_SESSION['cart']** is an array contains arrays of **$line**

```
 $line = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'type' => $type,
        'quantity' => $quantity,
        'price' => $price,
        'picture' => $dish->getPicture()->getWebPath(),
    );
```

This is the output of $_SESSION['cart']:
[image]

As you see in th last array with **id 55 and type "french bred"** , what I'd like to do is to check if th user chose the same product but a with different type so insert new line else if the same product and the same type so just update quantity.

Comment: And the problem with this code is?

Comment: What should `$_SESSION['cart']` look like? You're currently checking if `$_SESSION['cart'][$type]` exists. Is that correct?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: You are searching for a key with value of $id, so if $id is '5' for example, there must be a key '5', but the keys in the array are 'id', 'type' etc. You should loop through cart, iterate over each $line and do if($line['id'] === $id) etc

Comment: I have updated my quetsion with output of $_session['cart'] an some description  :)

Comment: @u_mulder , the problem is that the cart is no more updated with the second code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do, however the question is too vague and too little code is shown for me to properly understand your problem

```
$lineExists = false;
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $index => $line){
        if($line['id'] === $id)
        {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$index]['quantity'] += $quantity;
            $lineExists = true;
        }
    }
    if(!$lineExists)
    {
        $_SESSION['cart'][] = $newLine;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if type and id exists then you should do something like this

```
if (array_key_exists('id', $_SESSION['cart']) && array_key_exists('type', $_SESSION['cart'])) {
  // stuff here..
}
```

if $id is the value of the key id so 'id' => 5 then you should check like this:

```
if ($_SESSION['cart']['type'] == $id) {
 // stuff here
}
```

Hope this somewhat helps you further!